# How to retrieve mapping datasource tableName for an entity without Table annotation?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I need to retrieve the database table name of a certain entity using only my **EntityManager** instance, is that possible?

Or any way to load all mapped tables with related entity classes.

PS.: I'm using Hibernate v4.2.7 without Annotations

Comment: The JPA spec *defines* what the table name will be for an entity when no annotation/XML is specified, so no need to resort to provider-specific handling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get that from hibernate SessionFactory once you strip it out of the EntityManager:

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;

public String getTableName(Class entityClass){

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = ((Session) entityManager.getDelegate()).getSessionFactory();

    ClassMetadata classMetadata = sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(entityClass);

    SessionFactoryImpl sessionFactoryImpl = (SessionFactoryImpl) sessionFactory;

    AbstractEntityPersister entityPersister 
            = (AbstractEntityPersister) sessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(classMetadata.getEntityName());

    return entityPersister.getTableName();
}
```

Could not find appropriate API to use plain EntityManager.
If you are allowed to work with the implementation then this worked for me.

Comment: Thank you! Worked fine with just a little modifications!

Answer (score 1):

Maciej answer was missing some code and I found a way to do with less steps:

```
private String getTableName ( Class entityClass ) {

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = ( ( Session ) getEntityManager().getDelegate() ).getSessionFactory();

    AbstractEntityPersister persister = ( AbstractEntityPersister ) sessionFactory.getClassMetadata( entityClass );

    return persister.getTableName();
}
```

*I have tried to edit his answer but was rejected =/*

Comment: Its possible with less steps, but my solution was not missing anything to compile and work m8.

Comment: You missed the last word and semicolon at the end of line here:
    SessionFactoryImpl sessionFactoryImpl = ( SessionFactoryImpl ) sessionFactory;
Nothing critical, your answer was great! but less code is just a simple refactor to simplificate that and make things more understandable.

Comment: Right, i overlooked that part, thanks. When it comes to refactoring.. in prod code always, but when you are passing information for others to learn, a bit more to make the steps clearer makes sense to me. Anyway, good spot on that shorter version possibility.